# Trunking across different switch makes

Tags: switch, vlan, trunk

I have a Dell N3132PX running 6 different VLANs. (192.xxx.xxx.10)

VLAN 2 is my management VLAN for my switches.
VLAN 3 is my DHCP network running production level for users.

Port 25 (Untagged) VLAN 2 PVID 2 is where my server with my DHCP is running Active Directory and DNS.
Port 32 is my Trunk Port (Tagged) PVID 1. (As far as I understand all VLANs should be running through here).

Port 32 Trunk runs to a Black Box LGB2118A 18 port switch (192.xxx.xxx.13).
This connection is made at Port 16 Trunked (Tagged) PVID 1.

I have 2 computers on ports 11 & 12 VLAN 2 (Untagged) PVID2 plugged in.

Problems:
1. Black Box switch cannot ping Dell Switch.
2. Computers cannot ping server or access server.

Do I have my trunk port setup incorrectly? I have double checked all the options and definitions of trunking an I feel I might be missing something or have something configured incorrectly. I would post the configs to the question but the websense here is blocking me to adding files to any website to do so. Happy to add more information if needed.

**EDIT:** Adding requested Port Information:

```
Port Gil/0/32
VLAN Membership Mode: Trunk Mode
Access Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
General Mode PVID: 1 (default)
General Mode Ingress Filtering: Enabled
General Mode Acceptable Frame Type: Admit All
General Mode Dynamically Added VLANs:
General Mode Untagged VLANs: 1
General Mode Tagged VLANs:
General Mode Forbidden VLANs:
Trunking Mode Native VLAN: 3
Trunking Mode Native VLAN Tagging: 2-4074
Trunking Mode: VLANs Enabled: All
Private VLAN Host Association: none
Private VLAN Mapping:
Private VLAN Operational Bindings:
Default Priority: 0
Protected: Disabled
```

**EDIT:** After setting PVID on Black Board Switch to 2 I can now ping the Dell switch from the Black Box switch on VLAN2. Problem remaining is that I can't ping the server through the switch on VLAN 3 NOR get a valid address through my DHCP on VLAN 3. Here are the Black Box settings. This switch has now CLI.

[image: VLAN Settings]
[image]

**EDIT:** Port information for the Dell Port 25 where the server is plugged in.

```
Port Gil/0/25
VLAN Membership Mode: Access Mode
Access Mode VLAN: 3
General Mode PVID: 1 (default)
General Mode Ingress Filtering: Enabled
General Mode Acceptable Frame Type: Admit All
General Mode Dynamically Added VLANs:
General Mode Untagged VLANs: 1
General Mode Tagged VLANs:
General Mode Forbidden VLANs:
Trunking Mode Native VLAN: 1 (default)
Trunking Mode Native VLAN Tagging: Disabled
Trunking Mode: VLANs Enabled: All
Private VLAN Host Association: none
Private VLAN Mapping:
Private VLAN Operational Bindings:
Default Priority: 0
Protected: Disabled
```

Computer trying to access the server on VLAN 3 is plugged into Port 9 on the Black Box switch above.

Comment: Have you assigned all the VLANs to the trunk interfaces, and are they tagged?

Comment: Can you post the configuration of the Dell switch, in particular, your trunk ports?

Comment: @RonMaupin yes they are.

Comment: @RonTrunk Added.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Added.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui that is already done. See the first picture above. Port 16 has all VLAN allowed through the trunk.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Trunk 16 is Trunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking with multiple people and Black Box here is what fixed the issue.

First on the Dell the native VLAN on the trunk port 32 needed to be set to 1 (default)

On the Black Box switch the Trunk Port (port 16) needed to be set as a C-Port and then the switch had to be restarted. PVID on Black Box switch remains at 2.

Special thanks to @RonTrunk for his help on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

VLAN trunks don't automatically forward all VLANs. Each VLAN must be activated on a trunk. One VLAN may be untagged (native), all others must be tagged. The trunk has to be set up in the same way on both sides.

Comment: Please see updated question. VLANs 2-4074 allowed.